# How to redirect any http to https and remove www in aws using .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, amazon-route53

I want to redirect all request to `https` in amazon web service. I am using EC2 (window server 2012), Load Balancer and Route 53.

What I want:

```
http://www.example .com
```

to

```
 https://example.com
```

And

```
http://example.com
```

to

```
https:// example .com
```

I tried to do it with .htaccess but getting failed every time.

Comment: Please show the contents of the .htaccess file you're trying.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The first rule-set redirects everything to `https://`

The second rule-set redirects all `www.` subdomains to the TLD (without www)

`R=301` means the content is permanently moved. If you only want to move it temporary you have to use `R=302`

Check [Wikipedia: List of HTTP status codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) for more information

Comment: your code is not working on all conditions. when we hit URL without www it  does not redirect to https:// please provide if you have any solution regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

The below code is worked for me to redirect from www/HTTP with a subdomain to HTTPS. I am using APACHE Server in and it should work

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have SSL Certificate on your website, you can automatically redirect visitors to the secured (HTTPS) version of your website to make sure their information is protected.
using following code in htaccess you can automatically redirects all http request to https

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^apache-redirect-http-to-https\.html$
https://www.yoursite.com/apache-redirect-http-to-https.html [R=301,L]
```